# Android x86 on VirtualBox: App crashes on startup

Tags: android, crash, virtualbox

I am running Android x86 (64-bit) on VirtualBox. I'm able to access some apps fine, but some apps crash on startup every time. `logcat` shows this error:

`02-07 14:20:49.901  3083  3083 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.chase.sig.android-TPinjV5wbyLsmB6IHnEPmw==/lib/arm/libb.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40 (EM_ARM)`

Detailed info:

- My computer is running macOS Catalina
- ISO: Android-x86 64-bit 9.0-rc2 from FossHub (https://www.fosshub.com/Android-x86.html)
- VirtualBox OS: Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64 bit)
- VirtualBox specs: 6gb allocated RAM, 8gb hard drive. 3 processors. 128 MB video memory.
- Graphics controller: VBoxVGA without acceleration (I have tried the other options. Most alternatives prevent the OS from booting normally at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this application ships with native ARM libraries only. You can check it up with the following steps:

1. Obtain APK for the app
2. Unzip the APK
3. Under its lib folder, you will see folders names after architectures like arm64-v8a  armeabi-v7a  x86  x86_64
4. Check if x86 and/or x86_64 contain libb.so file

P.S. How do you install it? Apk or Google Play?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Under lib, there is only armeabi-v7a. However in assets/libs there is also x86/native_app and x86/native_app_pie without the .so extension. I installed via Google Play. Follow up questions: does this mean that the app only supports 32 bit OS? This seems strange. Also, since there is x86/native_app in assets/libs, would this app work in an x86 VirtualBox, or does the file need to be an .so in lib? All other advice appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for delay - I was pretty busy.  I had a look on the app (installed on an ARM device). First of all, I believe this nativeapp file is a part of security framework - it lies in assets along with what looks like code for vulnerability detection. Secondly, if you can install app from Google Play means that support for x86 is declared. This is somewhat corroborated by the fact that there are x86 executables in assets. Thirdly, there are files in the apk  that should not be in production at all.

Comment: Taking into account all of the above and the fact that  the application relies on a set of obfuscated native libs (this is common for this type of applications) and you don't have them under <apk root>/lib/x86, I believe that this is a build issue. I would ask the vendor if they actually support x86.